# Psycopg2, selection based on date/time

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to be able select from a certain time frame from a database. This is what I have right now, but it just selects all rows.

```
try:
    cur.execute("SELECT * from people_counter")
except:
    print "cannot select from node"
    sys.exit()

node_rows = cur.fetchall()
```

The database is setup with three rows such that it looks like this,

> unit_id, time_stamp, direction
>
> text, timestamp with time zone, text

The database is a Postgresql DB, using python and pyscopg2 as the wrapper.

I just don't exactly understand how I specify a certain column in the DB as the date/time in order to select rows only from a certain time frame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the values in the query,

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * 
               FROM people_counter 
               WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN 
                   date '2015-06-01' and 
                   date '2015-06-30';""")
```

or [as parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

```
import datetime as dt
cur.execute("""SELECT * 
               FROM people_counter 
               WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN %s and %s;""", 
            (dt.date(2015,6,1), dt.date(2015,6,30)))
```